# Need help on PHP pagination

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I have put together a pagination code where it should pull data from a zip code table and return all zip codes within a certain radius. Pagination works and it displays the results with the click on page number links at the bottom. It all looks good until you click on the second, 3rd or any page after. No information will be displayed :(

Here is my code. This is the search page

search.html

```
    <form action="search.php" method="post">
        <label>Enter your ZIP Code: <input type="text" name="zipcode" size="6" maxlength="5" </label>
        <br />
        <label>Select a distance in miles from this point:</label>
        <select name="d">
            <option>5</option>
            <option>10</option>
            <option>25</option>
            <option>50</option>
            <option>100</option>
        </select>

        <br />


        <br /> 
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
```

This is the code to do the search and display results in pagination format

Just can't figure out the issue. If I change my query to pull every line from table zips, then there are no issues. It only gives me the issue when I ask, `"SELECT from $tble_name WHERE ...`.

```
<?php

$d=$_POST['d']; $zipcode=$_POST['zipcode'];
//*  -------- CONNECT TO MY DATABASE --------- *//
$sql2="SELECT * FROM zips WHERE zipcode='$zipcode'"; 
$result2=mysql_query($sql2); $count=mysql_num_rows($result2);
if($count==1)  {

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2))   {
        $lat1 = $row['Latitude']; $lon1 = $row['Longitude'];
    } 
}
$r = 3959;

$latN = rad2deg(asin(sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * cos($d / $r) +
   cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin($d / $r) * cos(deg2rad(0))));

$latS = rad2deg(asin(sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * cos($d / $r) +
   cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin($d / $r) * cos(deg2rad(180))));
                             $lonE = rad2deg(deg2rad($lon1) + 
 atan2(sin(deg2rad(90)) * sin($d / $r) * cos(deg2rad($lat1)), cos($d / $r) -
   sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin(deg2rad($latN))));
                             $lonW = rad2deg(deg2rad($lon1) + 
 atan2(sin(deg2rad(270)) * sin($d / $r) * cos(deg2rad($lat1)), cos($d / $r) 
 sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin(deg2rad($latN))));

$adjacents = 2;     

$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM zips WHERE (Latitude <= $latN
   AND Latitude >= $latS AND Longitude <= $lonE AND Longitude >= $lonW)
   AND city != ''";

$total_pages = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));  
$total_pages = $total_pages[num];

$targetpage = "search.php"; 
$limit = 10;
$page = $_GET['page'];
if($page)   
    $start = ($page - 1) * $limit;
else   
    $start = 0;          

$query3 = "SELECT * FROM zips WHERE (Latitude <= $latN AND Latitude
   >= $latS AND Longitude <= $lonE AND Longitude >= $lonW) AND city != '' 
  ORDER BY state, city, Latitude, Longitude LIMIT $start, $limit";

$result3 = mysql_query($query3);
if ($page == 0) 
    $page = 1;  

$prev = $page - 1;  
$next = $page + 1;        
$lastpage = ceil($total_pages/$limit);

$lpm1 = $lastpage - 1;   

$pagination = "";  
if($lastpage > 1)  {    
    $pagination.= "<div
   class=\"pagination\">";   //previous button   if ($page > 1)    
   $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$prev\">« previous</a>";  
   else    $pagination.= "<span class=\"disabled\">« previous</span>"; 
        //pages    if ($lastpage < 7 + ($adjacents * 2))  //not enough pages 
  to bother breaking it up   {     for ($counter = 1; $counter <=
   $lastpage; $counter++)    {
       if ($counter == $page)
        $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
       else
        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";         
  }   }  
   elseif($lastpage > 5 + ($adjacents * 2))  //enough pages to hide some
   {    //close to beginning; only hide later pages    if($page < 1 +
   ($adjacents * 2))      {
       for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($adjacents * 2); $counter++)
       {
        if ($counter == $page)
         $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
        else
         $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";     
       }
       $pagination.= "...";
       $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lpm1\">$lpm1</a>";
       $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lastpage\">$lastpage</a>";      
   }    //in
   middle; hide some front and some back    elseif($lastpage -
   ($adjacents * 2) > $page && $page > ($adjacents * 2))    {
       $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=1\">1</a>";
       $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=2\">2</a>";
       $pagination.= "...";
       for ($counter = $page - $adjacents; $counter <= $page + $adjacents; 
   $counter++)
       {
        if ($counter == $page)
         $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
        else
         $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";     
       }
       $pagination.= "...";
       $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lpm1\">$lpm1</a>";
       $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lastpage\">$lastpage</a>";      }    //close
   to end; only hide early pages    else    {   $pagination.= "<a
   href=\"$targetpage?page=1\">1</a>";   $pagination.= "<a
   href=\"$targetpage?page=2\">2</a>";
       $pagination.= "...";
       for ($counter = $lastpage - (2 + ($adjacents * 2)); $counter <= 
   $lastpage; $counter++)
       {
        if ($counter == $page)
         $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
        else
         $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";     
       }    }   }
        //next button   if ($page < $counter - 1)     $pagination.= "<a 
  href=\"$targetpage?page=$next\">next »</a>";   else    $pagination.=
   "<span class=\"disabled\">next »</span>";   $pagination.= "</div>\n";
   } ?>



   <?php echo "<table align='center', border='1',table width='90%',
   cellpadding='0', cellspacing='0'  class='zui-table
   zui-table-rounded'>";

   echo "<tr>";

   echo "<td>" . "<font color='black', face='verdana',
   size='2'><b>City</b></font></td>"; echo "<td>" . "<font
   color='black', face='verdana', size='2'><b>State</b></font></td>";
   echo "<td>" . "<font color='black', face='verdana', size='2'><b>Zip
   Code</b></font></td>";

   echo "</tr>";

      while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result3)) {



   echo "<tr>";

   echo "<td align='left'><font color='black', face='verdana',
   size='2'>" . $row['city'] . "</font></td>";

   echo "<td align='left'><font color='black', face='verdana',
   size='2'>" . $row['state'] . "</font></td>";

   echo "<td align='left'><font color='black', face='verdana',
   size='2'>" . $row['zipcode'] . "</font></td>";

   echo "</tr>\n";


       }


   echo "</table>\n<br />\n";


   ?>

      <br>


   <?=$pagination?>   </html>
```

Comment: Please try and properly format this code. Usually the `{}` button gets it right, but otherwise, indenting with four spaces fixes it.

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not use the [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It’s so awful and dangerous that it was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices. Your user data is **not** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html) and there are [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) and can be exploited.

Comment: I do not see `SELECT from $tble_name WHERE ....` anywhere.

Comment: Your code only assumes that the various sql calls are successful, it does not check if that's the case.